# Convert Database datetime or date in Javascript new Date(GMT) format

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to Convert Database date Like mm/dd/yyyy , dd/mm/yyyy, yyyy/mm/dd to new Date() (GMT) Or (IST) format in javascript

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a JS library called moment.js to simplify all date's management.

Example:

```js
moment("12/25/2016", "MM/DD/YYYY").format("Format/you/want");
```

Source: http://momentjs.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

you could use `toUTCString()` Method

```
var d = new Date("Your date"); 
var n = d.toUTCString();
```

This returns GMT format,
hope this is what you were looking for :)